# find $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\tan^2 (x)}\bigg)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

What is the solution of

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\tan^2 (x)}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 2):

We find a common denominator, and taylor expand:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\tan^2(x)-x^2}{x^2\tan^2{x}}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^4+O(x^5)-x^2}{x^2(x^2+O(x^4))}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\frac{2}{3}x^4+O(x^5)}{x^
4+O(x^5))}\right)=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Can we use l'hopital rule twice since the fraction equals 0/0?

Comment: Of course...if you check that after the first application it is still an indeterminant form. This was just one way of doing it, there perhaps avoided some messier derivatives (because you can find the first few terms of the Taylor series for $\tan^2(x)$ from the series for $\tan(x)$.

Comment: @M.H. Using L'Hospital would require four iterations, not two.

Comment: Can we solve it by using trigonometric roles?

Comment: @helloworld112358 In your solution,  equal (=) or approximate??

Comment: Because I am using Big-O notation for the error terms, it is indeed equality. See for instance https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/ for an introduction to Big-O notation

Answer (score 1):

The limit is easily solved via Taylor series or L'Hospital's Rule. Using any of these techniques it is easy to show in one step that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - x} {x^{3}}=\frac{1}{3}$$ and now we can see that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{\tan^{2}x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - x} {x^{3}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\tan x} {x} \right)\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{\tan^{2}x}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot 2\cdot 1=\frac{2}{3}$$ The use of Taylor's series or L'Hospital's Rule should always be combined with elementary algebraic manipulation and the standard limits to avoid any complications. And repeated application of L'Hospital's Rule should be avoided at any cost.

Comment: I think it equals $-\frac{2}{3}$..

Comment: @M.H.: Thanks for catching typo. Answer is $2/3$. I had written $x-\tan x$ in place of $\tan x - x$. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Taylor expansion: $$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+O(x^8)$$
we get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+1\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{1-\cos(2x)}\right)+1=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\left(1-\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^4}{4!}+O(x^6)\right)-2x^2}{x^2\left(1-\left(1-\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^4}{4!}+O(x^6)\right)\right)}+1=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{-\frac23 x^4+O(x^6)}{2x^4+O(x^6)}+1=-\frac13+1=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit equals
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan^2x-x^2}{x^4}
$$
because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$. Now we can look separately at
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x+x}{x}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}
$$
The former equals
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x+x\cos x}{x\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+o(x))+x(1+o(1))}{x\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x+o(x)}{x\cos x}=2
$$
The latter equals
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-x^3/6+o(x^3))-x(1-x^2/2+o(x^2))}{x^3\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3/3+o(x)}{x^3\cos x}=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: The closed is infront of you

Comment: What is the strange comment for you? :-( After when you have written a comment of a difficult of a limit I have had a little smile :-)